# The system running in low grapics mode

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.02. I have a NVIDIA GF104 GeForce GTX 460

`lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D`
command output:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF104 [GeForce GTX 460] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

`cat /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-331/331.113/build/make.log` output:
  http://paste.ubuntu.com/11967705

[dmesg output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11967924)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26487/discussion-on-question-by-genkbejo-the-system-running-in-low-grapics-mode-please).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest booting to recovery console and running

```
mount -o remount,rw /
apt-get purge nvidia*
apt-get install nvidia-331
reboot
```

If this does not help, I suggest upgrading kernel from recovery

```
mount -o remount,rw /
apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

It looks that there is some compatibility problem with the standard nvidia package. Run this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

and reboot.